# TableView inside UIView doesn't show up Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, tableview

I’m having a problem with embedding tableView inside a UIView. I tell you what my goal is:
My goal is to have a little tableView with 3 rows (like here - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaCP1.jpg)), now I’ve made a custom UIView with a tableView inside but for some reason it doesn’t load my data + doesn’t show anything. I must be honest I’m not sure if it is the right way of doing that, cause maybe there’s a better way of doing that, so I hope you guys can help me out.

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



class TypeTableView:  UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var typesData = ["Videos","Images","Posts"]
    
    
    var tableView = UITableView()
    
//    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
//    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
//

    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .red
        
        setup()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    
    func setup() {
        
        
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 100),style: .grouped)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .red
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.addSubview(tableView)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return typesData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = typesData[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's the custom cell of the tableView(the tableView is inside the customCell):

```
import UIKit

class ByType: UITableViewCell {
    
    
//    var typesData = ["Videos","Images","Posts"]

    
    @IBOutlet var groupedTableView: TypeTableView!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        

        
//        self.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)

        groupedTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        groupedTableView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        groupedTableView.backgroundColor = .red
        groupedTableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Well, the code you posted will crash in `setup()` because you're adding constraints before adding the `tableView` as a subview. After moving `self.addSubview(tableView)` prior to adding the constraints, it seems to work fine. Perhaps you're not setting constraints properly on the instance of `TypeTableView` you create in your view controller (which you haven't shown here)?

Comment: Using a table view inside a table view cell is not good solution. You need to use a stackview inside ByType